# User object is not being detected even though mentioned in Model?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm trying to setup comments by showing document data and mapping it to a readable view.

Inside my Comment Model, I have setup a user object.

However, when attempting to pull data about this user, my app crashes and gives me the error:

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

My code is below:

**Comment Model:**

```
struct Comment: Identifiable, Decodable {
@DocumentID var id: String?
let caption: String
let timestamp: Timestamp
let photoUrl: String?
let uid: String
var likes: Int
var replyingTo: String?

var user: User?
var didLike: Bool? = false

var timestampString: String {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfMonth]
    formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
    formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
    return formatter.string(from: timestamp.dateValue(), to: Date()) ?? ""
}

var detailedTimestampString: String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a · MM/dd/yyyy"
    return formatter.string(from: timestamp.dateValue())
}
}
```

**User Model:**

```
struct User: Identifiable, Decodable {
@DocumentID var id: String?
let username: String
let name: String
let bio: String
let website: String
let location: String
let profileImageUrl: String
let email: String
var badgeBeta: Bool
var badgeAdmin: Bool
var disabled: Bool
var verified: Bool
var locked: Bool
var followers: Int
var following: Int

var isCurrentUser: Bool { return Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == id }
}
```

**CommentsRowView** [CAUSING THE ERROR]:

```
struct CommentsRow: View {

var post : Post
var comment : Comment
@ObservedObject var commentData : CommentsViewModel
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            KFImage(URL(string: comment.user!.profileImageUrl))
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                
            Text(comment.user!.id)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .font(Font.custom("CircularStd-Bold", size: 18))
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
            
            Text("•")
            
            Text(comment.timestampString)
                .font(Font.custom("CircularStd-Medium", size: 13))
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        Text(comment.caption)
            .font(Font.custom("CircularStd-Light", size: 15))
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
    }
    .padding(.bottom, 5)
}
}
```

It should be noted that my user object works fine throughout the rest of my application.

Comment: you are using forced unwrapping (`!`) in a number of places, this is a well known recipe for disaster. **Do not use** forced unwrapping anywhere in your code. Read the swift basics for alternatives. On which line do you get the error?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine the error appears when I attempt to pull the comment.user.username & comment.user.profileImageUrl

Comment: You don't show the code where you use `comment.user.username`. I suspect the code you show is not the code that produces your errors. In any case, it is a simple to fix, 
 as you would have found in the **Swift basics docs**. Use `if comment.user != nil { // do somehting }`, or `if let theUser = comment.user { // do something with theUser}`. Do the same for **every** forced unwrapping you have.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my commentviewmodel with:

```
    didSet {
        if let post = post {
            getComments(id: post.id!) { comments in
                self.comments = comments
                
                for i in 0 ..< comments.count {
                    let uid = comments[i].uid
                    
                    self.userService.fetchUser(withUid: uid) { user in
                        self.comments[i].user = user
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and it now works